# changing port number for solr-4.3.1

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have been using solr 3 and now I am plan to switch to solr 4. The port that I want to run solr on is 9090 instead of 8080. AFAIK, to change the port number we configure the solr.xml file. The entry in my solr.xml file looks like the following:

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1" host="${host:}" hostPort="9090" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}">
<core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />
```

What is surprising is, when I hit the url: 
    http://[domain]:9090/solr/admin.. it says page not found, but 
    http://[domain]:8983/solr/>.. works just as fine even after changing the port number. I am sure I am missing out something. Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are trying to run `Solr` on `Jetty`? The one which comes with it?

Answer (score 18):

The port value in solr.xml is for Solr Cloud and is not actually where the listen port is defined for the server.

That port is defined (for default Jetty configuration) in **jetty.xml** file in the **example/etc** directory. Try changing it there or overriding it from the command line:

> java -Djetty.port=9999 -jar start.jar

Answer (score 6):

For Solr 5.4.1 you don't have to change any config files. Just run the following command in the Command Prompt to start solr on port number XXXX:

```
solr-5.4.1\bin\solr start -p XXXX
```

To stop run this command:

```
solr-5.4.1\bin\solr stop -p XXXX
```